# windows 10 properly installing JAR files for JVM

Tags: java, maven, jce

I am entirely new to Java so please refer me to a similar question if this is a duplicate.  I did not see an answer specific to my problem.

I am working to get my environment up and running with **maven**

The error I came across

```
[project name] requires that the high-encryption JAR files be installed for the JVM used to build the project.
```

So i went to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html. To get the java cryptography extension.

I downloaded the extension and and compressed it.  At this point I am expecting to be able to get past the **high-encryption ** error that was blocking me.

[image]

Unfortunately,  I am still getting the same error from above.  Not sure what else I need to do to get this working. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend that you read the README file. It has an installation section. You have downloaded the files but they need to be installed before they can be used.

Answer (score 1):

With maven, use your POM.xml file to fetch your dependencies.